# Updating cache object that contains collection of employees

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, caching, memorycache

I have a collection of Employees that I stored inside `MemoryCache.Now` after update of particular employee details, I want to update the **same** cache object with updated employee details. Something like that:

```
var AllEmployees= cache.Get("AllEmployees");
if(AllEmployees != null)
{
       var empToUpdate = AllEmployees.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EmpId== Employee.EmpId);
       if (empToUpdate != null)
       {
           AllEmployees.Remove(empToUpdate );
           AllEmployees.add(empToUpdate ); 
      }
}
```

but since cache is memory cache and it has cached `IEnumerable<Employee>,`i am not able to directly manipulate cache object.I am not able to call these methods **FirstOrDefault,Remove,Add**

Comment: Why you cant use FirstOrDefault? IEnumerable supports FirstOrDefault

Comment: What kind of error are you getting while you attempt a call to the methods FirstOrDefault, is it not available ? Reason for the same is Cache.Get will give you an base object class type, and you need to explicitly type cast to the IEnumerable<Employee> to call the required methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment i cant see a reason to no use FirstOrDefault.
IEnumerables are not ment to be modified. So you have to go a heavy, performanceunfirendly way and create a new IEnumerable without a specific item (*IENumerable.Except(array of items to exclude)*) then yo gonna concat it with another sequenze, which contains your new element to add.

```
   var empToUpdate = AllEmployees.FirstOrDefault(i => i.EmpId== Employee.EmpId);
   if (empToUpdate != null)
   {
      AllEmployees = AllEmployees.Except(new[]{empToUpdate}).Concat(new[] { empToUpdate});
  }
```

Anyways i dont see a sense in this code, cause you are removing the object  and immediatly add it again.

Comment: Why IEnumerable type cannot be modified, various collections like List is an IEnumerable<T> type. Only when we have obtained an enumerator, then a collection cannot be modified, since that would invalidate the enumerator like modifying the collection in a foreach loop